# SimpleXmlElement constructor generates error on one server, but doesn't on another

Tags: xml, rss, simplexml, php

I used the same piece of code with the same test URL. My localhost and my public web server both run Ubuntu, they both have Simplexml support enabled and Schema support enabled. My localhost runs PHP Version 5.4.6-1ubuntu1.1, the public web server runs PHP Version 5.3.19.

The line of code that generates the error is a simple constructor:

```
$x = new SimpleXmlElement($file, NULL, TRUE);
```

Which is in a try-catch block because it has a simple purpose to validate RSS files (ironic that it doesn't work).

On the localhost it's fine, while on the webserver i get the error saying

> Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: META line 1 and head in ... on line ...

What COULD possibly be the cause of this?

I should note that this particular RSS channel i've tested this with, does not validate on the W3 validator. So I guess my question would have to be how come my localhost works with it? (beyond the constructor, it reads the items just fine and works with them).

The only thing I found that's SimpleXml-related in the PHP changelog for versions past 5.3.19 is this:

> Implemented FR #55218 (Get namespaces from current node).

But I don't think that has anything to do with this particular situation really... does it?

Comment: The error is here `Opening and ending tag mismatch: META line 1 and head in ... on line ...`

Comment: Is it xml or HTML. if its xml it should be valid. Its better to use DOM for parsing XML and HTML. Please show sample string you want to parse and the code you are using to parse it.

Comment: The code is in the original question (it's just the constructor that generates the error). The URL is http://thewatchers.adorraeli.com/feed/

Comment: I think your data is truncated for some reason. Also the feed does not allow multiple request. From the next request it returns 403.